# Powershell scripts fails during bootstrap but works post first chef-client run

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I have the below recipe which executes a power shell command:

```
powershell_script 'Install' do
    cwd 'C:\scripts'
    code <<-EOH
    powershell C:\\scripts\\pair.ps1 -repo-host #{repohost} -repo-dir #{repodir} -repo-https-port #{repohttpsport} -management-server #{managementserver} -activation-code #{activationcode} -env #{env} -loc #{loc} -role #{role} -app #{app}; Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope process undefined -Force;
    EOH
end
```

The recipe basically downloads a pair.sh file from the internet and stores it in the c:\scripts directory.
This is achieved in the first part of the cookbook.

During the bootstrap it is added to the node and post bootstrap it runs the chef-client as part of the botstrap and it fails with the below errors:

```
ec2-13-232-54-174.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com     Error executing action `run` on resource 'powershell_script[Insta
ll]'
ec2-13-232-54-174.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com     =================================================================
===============
ec2-13-232-54-174.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
ec2-13-232-54-174.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com     **

 - Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed

**
ec2-13-232-54-174.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com     ------------------------------------
ec2-13-232-54-174.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com     Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
ec2-13-232-54-174.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com     ---- Begin output of "powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -No
Profile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -InputFormat None -Command ". 'C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/chef_powershell_scri
pt-user-code20180502-2840-7o4rwn.ps1'" ----
ec2-13-232-54-174.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com     STDOUT:
ec2-13-232-54-174.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com     STDERR: Thread failed to start.
ec2-13-232-54-174.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com     ---- End output of "powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoPr
ofile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -InputFormat None -Command ". 'C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/chef_powershell_script
-user-code20180502-2840-7o4rwn.ps1'" ----
ec2-13-232-54-174.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com     Ran "powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Executio
nPolicy Bypass -InputFormat None -Command ". 'C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/chef_powershell_script-user-code20180
502-2840-7o4rwn.ps1'" returned 1
ec2-13-232-54-174.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com [2018-05-02T17:49:46+00:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFail
ed: powershell_script[Install] (illumio2::default line 39) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected
process to exit with [0], but received '1'
ERROR: Failed to execute command on ec2-13-232-54-174.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com return code 1
ERROR: Bootstrap command returned 1
```

Once the bootstrap fails, when i manually run the chef-clinet run on this node this completes successfully.

It is a strange behavior that it fails during bootstrap but the same command works on the first chef-client run

Any leads on fixing this error is greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `powershell_script` there and not `execute`? That doesn't look like powershell code, it looks like a command.

Answer (score 0):

Try raising your `MaxMemoryPerShellMB` in winrm with a command like `winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="1024"}'`. [This ticket](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4814) for chef is pretty old but reports a similar problem.